# How to disable next button on multipart form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, multipartform-data

So I have a multipart form I am working on where I would like to check the values of each step and run some basic validation on the input fields in that step. I can't seem to figure out how to prevent the form from moving to the next step if fails the validation. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

```html
<body>
  <form name="form1" action="test.php" method="POST">
    <div id="page1" data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Page1</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="group1">
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
          <label for="age">age</label>
        </fieldset>
        <a href="#page2" data-role="button" id="btnPage2">Next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" data-role="page">
      <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Page2</h1>
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="group2">
          <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the submition of the form on the button click if its not valid you need to return false to the click event. Here is [my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73wmf9fa/)

```
    $("#btnPage2").click(function() {
        var isValid = true;//added local variable to track validation
        $("#group1 input[type=text]").each(function() {
            if((this.value) == "") {
                isValid = false;//form was not valid
                return false;
            }
        });  
        if (! isValid) {//when form is not valid, return false
            return false;
        }
    });
```

As requested, this is how I would do it when i want to bind the event to all btnPage buttons. It retrieves the group number that the button is on (in this case the number at the end of your `btnPage` minus 1 is the group number) and uses it in the each statement for validation. [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/73wmf9fa/1/)

```
$('a[id^="btnPage"]').click(function() {
    var groupNum = +($(this).attr('id').replace('btnPage', '')) - 1;//get the group number to validate
    var isValid = true;//added local variable to track validation
    $('#group' + groupNum + ' input[type=text]').each(function() {
        if(this.value == "") {
            isValid = false;//form was not valid
            return false;
        }
    });  
    if (! isValid) {//when form is not valid, return false
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: So do you know how to write a function using your code that can pass in the identifiers i.e. #btnPage2/#group1, #btnPage3/#group2.... I plan on using this on multiple pages and to slim down on repeat code i think this would be perfect for a function....just not that sure on how to write one.

Comment: So a function the will handle this event for all btnPage# click events?

Comment: officially a god!!  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. At this moment im working on own mobile stuff so I'm in that mindset.

Comment: love it...just curious though ive never seen a selector like 'a[id^="btnPage"]' ....what does ^ do in your code?

Comment: When the ^ is used like that it means that the attribute begins with this string. (in this case) select all a elements with an id attribute that begins with "btnPage". You can see other similar selectors at this link: http://devdocs.io/css/attribute_selectors